# youtube api contentowner by video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

We are a content owner who has multiple channels rolled up into our analytics

We are pulling each day's earnings from the Youtube API to store in our database, but we want the data available per-video and not just per-channel.

The only way I've found to get a single video's earnings for a particular day is to do it for each individual video, like so

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=contentOwner%3D%3D<contentownerid>&start-date=2013-10-01&end-date=2013-10-01&metrics=views%2Cearnings&dimensions=day&filters=video%3D%3D<videoid>&sort=day&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This, obviously, is not ideal.  We have over 5000 videos we're trying to keep track of, and the number will only grow, so making thousands of API calls every morning is not a good solution.

Is there a way to get earnings reports for the whole channel, separated by video, for a given date range with a single API call? I would think I would set "dimension" to video, but that won't work with anything involving the monetary fields like earnings.